# Passing data from UIViewController to Custom UIView with XIB

Tags: swift

I have the following swift file which controls a xib file

```
import UIKit

protocol SelectProfile: class {
func selectionUp(id: Int, selected: Bool)
}

class Component: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var selection: UIView!

var selected: Bool = false
var profileId: Int = 6

weak var delegate: SelectProfile?

@IBAction func selProfile(_ sender: Any) {
    selected = !selected
    selection.isHidden = !selected
    delegate?.selectionUp(id: profileId, selected: selected)
}

let nibName = "Component"

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() {
    guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
    view.frame = self.bounds
    self.addSubview(view)

    selection.isHidden = true
    name.text = String(profileId)
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
    return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
}
}
```

In my UIViewController where I want to interact with the component I have the following code (shortened for brevity)

```
import UIKit

class Home: UIViewController, SelectProfile {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileComponent: Component!

    func selectionUp(id: Int, selected: Bool) {
        print(id, selected)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        profileComponent.delegate = self
        profileComponent.profileId = 2
    }
}
```

My delegate works nicely and I'm able to change the values for IBOutlets but I can't pass a value to variables. This line doesn't pass the data to my xib `profileComponent.profileId = 2`. 
It seems like I have an issue with initialization of the xib but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `viewDidLoad` of controller is called after view's `init`, so when you change `profileId` as you do, it is changed, but not reflected anywhere.

I assume the following, at least, missed:

```
var profileId: Int = 6 {
   didSet {
      name.text = String(profileId)
      // call delegate here if needed as well
   }
}
```